# Display the filtered existing post through category button when its clicked

Tags: php, categories, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

Anyone can help me. "my goal is to display the filtered existing post through category button when its clicked." I have a custom post added in my functions.php, through get_terms I've displayed the categories listed on my custom post. on my page, the echoed category is form as  dropdown, so when you choose and clicked the specific category, the filter function will occurred and display the specific post. here are my code so far:

here is the dropdown category list:

```
      <select class="custom-select sources" name="" id="dynamic_select">
         <div class="options">
            <option value="<?php echo home_url('/newsletter'); ?>" selected>All</option>                                        
                <?php
                   $args = array(
                   'orderby' => 'slug',
                   'order' => 'ASC',
                   'parent' => 0,
                   'hide_empty' => false
                  );
                   $terms = get_terms([
                   'taxonomy' => 'pdf_cat',
                   'hide_empty' => false,
                   ]);
                 foreach( $terms as $term ){
                 echo '<option class="ctg" value="'. get_term_link($term->term_id) .' ">' . $term->name . '</option>';                                                

                }
              ?>  
            </div>    
          </select>
```

when I clicked the category, it supposed to proceed to pdf_cat.php where the filter codes is located, but it won't connect.

here is the page where the categories was being clicked and displayed:

```
          <?php
            $terms = get_terms(); 
            $terms = $terms[0];                    
            $termsname = get_terms_name($terms->term_id);   
            $termsid = get_terms_ID($termsname);            
           ?>
                  
           <?php
             $paged = get_query_var('paged', 1);
             $args = array(                         
                'paged' => $paged,
                'post_type' => 'pdf',
                'taxonomy' => 'pdf_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
             );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);            
             
                global $query_string; 
                query_posts( $query_string . "&posts_per_page=12&paged=".$paged );
                  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
            ?>
```

from here, I can't able to display the filtered post

I added this Javacript:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#form").change(function(){
                var url = $(this).val();
                location.assign(url);
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: _"it supposed to proceed to pdf_cat.php where the filter codes is located, but it won't connect"_ - meaning what, exactly? Do you have a form element around this, with the correct action set? _"here is the page where the categories was being clicked"_ - so that is still part of the same page, where the select field was also displayed? So where is the code that is supposed to show the _filtered_ posts then?

Comment: With `name=""` that select field probably won't send much, even if it was inside a form.

Comment: hi @CBroe sorry for making you confused, I have to set of page to display all the custom post I made. 1st page is newsletter.php where all categories are posted. and the 2nd one is pdf_cat.php where the filtered category supposed to display. my goal is from newsletter.php category, once I clicked the specific category, it will proceed to pdf_cat.php to display the specific category that I've clicked

Comment: alright, I have changes on my code. I added javascript code to be able to proceed to the assigned link of the categories. the transition/ connection is fine. now the problem is, the display filtered category didn't display.

Comment: Based on what should this filter anything, the only dynamic value you inserted into the WP_Query, is $paged.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: my goal is to filter the specific custom taxonomy id through category

Comment: Then you need to add the proper filtering logic to your query - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: I have so many filtering logic trials I made, but all of these are not working. does anyone has same logic situation that is working fine?

Comment: You need to get the actual requested term from the URL first of all, so far it looks like you are not even doing that yet.

Comment: let me know how.

Comment: I think I have a problem on this area 
            $terms = get_terms(); 
            $terms = $terms[0];                    
            $termsname = get_terms_name($terms->term_id);   
            $termsid = get_terms_ID($termsname);

Comment: This just gets you all the terms, and then you pick the first one ... so this has nothing to do with whatever might get passed in the URL so far. It is unclear what those URLs you are navigating to actually _are_, whether that points to the archive page for the term, or whether you just made them up yourself? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/ should be able to get you the relevant parameter, if those are default WP pages.

Comment: I can't figure it out

Comment: Make a var_dump of get_queried_object(), and see what that gets you when you are on one of those pages.